# Measure theory book suggestion for a foundation to Probability theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, stochastic-calculus

I would like your comment (or another suggestions) on the 2 measure theory books for self-study:

1. Introduction to measure theory by Terence Tao
2. Measures, Integrals and Martingales by René L. Schilling

**My goal is to have only necessary foundations (because I don't want to go too deep in the measure theory)** to understand the rigorous foundation of probability (to the point of Brownian motion and Ito's calculus) and furthermore, the theoretical foundation of statistics ($i.e$ to understand the rigorous logic behind Maximum Likelihood Estimator or hypothesis testing, monte-carlo simulation).

1. Which measure theory book of these 2 books above will serve better for my purpose ?
2. Could you suggest me a book (good for self-study) on Probability/statistics which serve my purposes above ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know Tao's book, but I really enjoyed studying from Schilling's one. As far as I remember it doesn't cover topics on Stochastic calculus (BM, Ito calculus, etc), for this part you can try Schilling's "Brownian motion" book, and also "Introduction to stochastic integration" by Kuo

Comment: @Chaos: Hi, thanks for your response. How many months did you spend on study this book ? Do you feel comfortable with measure theory after learning the book ?

Comment: I think I've spent about 4 months with it. It was a good introduction, it allowed me to follow my more advanced PhD course in probability theory without major difficulties

Comment: @Chaos: Can you please suggest me a book on Probability which is based on measure theory ? (a book that explain the intuition and motivation of such a development of a concept). Thank you very much!

Comment: Mmm, maybe Billignsley's "Probability and measure"